# I am looking for suggestions when to use the HiveTemplate and when to use JDBC Template to query and manage data in Apache Hive

Tags: hive, spring-data

IMO, JDBC Template API is more mature and provides API to convert String based data into the Java POJOs. In which scenarios, HiveTemplate would be useful?

Any insights would be helpful. Thanks